# Puppeteer-PDF: Node hangs when I try to generate a PDF

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, puppeteer

I using Puppeteer to generate a PDF file. In my laptop (Windows 10) it works very well, but in the server (Windows Server 2012 R2) it hangs when it try to generate the PDF and it ends with time out error.

Here I set the variables and I call generatePdf() function

```
let html = '<html here....>';
pathPdf = 'c:\path\file.pdf'
    
const pdf=this.generatePdf();
    pdf.then(
        function (){
            res.status(200).send([{path: pathPdf}]);
        })
    .catch(
        function(val){
            res.status(500).send([val.message, val]);
    });
```

And the function that generates the PDF with Puppeteer:

```
this.generatePdf = async function() {
    return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
        try {
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
                headless: true
            });
            const page = await browser.newPage();
            page.setContent(html);
            //page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0)
            const buffer = await page.pdf({
                path: pathPdf,
                format: "A4",
                printBackground: true,
                displayHeaderFooter: true,
                footerTemplate: `
                <div style="font-size: 10px; padding-top: 5px; text-align: right; width: 100%; margin-right: 35px">
                <span>Page</span> <span class="pageNumber"></span> de <span class="totalPages"></span>
                </div>
                `,
                margin: {
                    bottom: 70, // minimum required for footer msg to display
                    left: 25,
                    right: 35,
                    top: 30,
                },
            });
            resolve();
            console.log('Bufffer', buffer);
            await browser.close();
            //res.end(buffer);
            console.log(buffer) // maybe do response(pdf).type('x-pdf')
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('Error', e);
            reject(e);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You've got a lot of `await` and `async` calls - at which line you get the timeout? First thing which comes to my mind - `pathPdf` is an absolute URI, you sure there's "C:\" drive on your server and you got write permissions there (not exactly **you,** but the user under which the script is being run)? Try to create a simple text file from within a script on the server to make sure that you actually can create files.

Comment: @MarekPiotrowski It hangs at the follow line: const page = await browser.newPage();
I created other file with fs without any problem at the same path

Comment: Try this one: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1262#issuecomment-448311449

Comment: @MarekPiotrowski The solution works, but now the HTML ignore some CSS code

Comment: @MarekPiotrowski I could fix the CSS problem, the problem now is that in the server generates the pdf empty

Comment: Even without the footer?